# How can $(\lnot q \lor r)$ become $(p \to r)$ in this context?

Tags: propositional-calculus

#### Question

Show that $(p\lor q)\rightarrow r\equiv(p\rightarrow r)\land(p\rightarrow r)$

#### Given solution

[image]

While I was taught that $(p\rightarrow r)\equiv( \neg p\lor r)$ which can be easily proven by a truth table...

but how is the last 2 statements in the given solution be possible? How is it possible that $(\neg q\lor r)$ transformed into $(p\rightarrow r)$? Is this a typo?

Comment: Yes. It's a typo. It should read $q\to r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a typo.](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((p%20%E2%88%A8%20q)%20%E2%86%92%20r)%20%E2%86%94((p%20%E2%86%92%20r)%20%E2%88%A7%20(p%20%E2%86%92%20r))) See [here](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((p%20%E2%88%A8%20q)%20%E2%86%92%20r)%20%E2%86%94((p%20%E2%86%92%20r)%20%E2%88%A7%20(q%20%E2%86%92%20r))) for the tableau of the intended statement

[image]